# How to convert .mov files to .mp4 (H264) using ffmpeg using windows .bat file?

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I have a number of different video files (mov, avi, flv, mp4, 3gp, wmv) in a folder.

I need to use a batch file that will convert all mov, avi, wmv, 3gp files in the folder
Also I need to skip any flv, mp4 files

I have this command, but it gives error and generates 0 size files:

```
for %%F in (*.mov) do ffmpeg.exe -i "%%~fF" -vcodec copy -acodec copy "%%~dpF\%%~nF.mp4"
```

The above line just tries to process mov files. I get same result for avi files.

I want to keep the file name same. I get the file names correctly but it gives error:

```
    ffmpeg version N-54691-g7f4a1fd Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jul 12 2013 16:31:48 with gcc 4.7.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-
amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --
enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 39.100 / 52. 39.100
  libavcodec     55. 18.102 / 55. 18.102
  libavformat    55. 12.102 / 55. 12.102
  libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
  libavfilter     3. 80.101 /  3. 80.101
  libswscale      2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, avi, from 'C:\musa\Challenge\FFMPEG\Test\file5.AVI':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : OPTURA20
  Duration: 00:00:10.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1518 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj422p, 320x240, 14.99 fps,
 14.99 tbr, 14.99 tbn, 14.99 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 16000 Hz, mono, s16,
256 kb/s
[mp4 @ 00000000024bc980] Tag [1][0][0][0]/0x00000001 incompatible with output co
dec id '65536' ([0][0][0][0])
Output #0, mp4, to 'C:\musa\Challenge\FFMPEG\Test\\file5.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : OPTURA20
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (l[0][0][0] / 0x006C), yuvj422p, 320x240, q=2-31,
14.99 fps, 90k tbn, 14.99 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 16000 Hz, mono, 256 k
b/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invali
d data found when processing input
```

Answer (score 4):

PCM audio streams are not compatible with the MP4 container, look at the [specs](http://www.mp4ra.org/codecs.html) and your error message:

```
Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 16000 Hz, mono, s16, 256 kb/s [mp4 @ 00000000024bc980] Tag [1][0][0][0]/0x00000001 incompatible with output codec id '65536' ([0][0][0][0])
```

Please note: the MP4 *video container format*  and the H.264 *video stream format* are two different things. The MP4  video container may also 'contain'  other video stream formats, eg. Xvid or even MJPEG.

Answer (score 1):

The video stream is MJPEG, if you really want MP4/H264 on the output, you should replace the

```
 -vcodec copy
```

by the -vcodec option to transcode your input video content

or add more complex stuff to detect when you can bypass the video stream and when a transcode is require.